# Which Google Maps API to enable to get http get to work

Tags: google-maps

I want to use this get in order to get Lat/Long for an address.

Currently, it always returns `REQUEST_DENIED`.  `This API project is not authorized to use this API.`

I have ensured that my  key is enabled, and currently, it has no restrictions for testing purposes.  This is the url, with the actual key replaced with `12345`.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=123%2C%20Harbor%2C%20Woods%20Circle%2C%20Safety%2C%20Harbor%2C%20FLCA%2C%2034695&key=12345
```

I have tried Disabling the Google Maps API, and then Enabling it again, but I still get the same error message.

I am thinking that maybe I don't have the right API enabled on this, as it should be working.

Comment: Your request works for me with one of my "unrestricted" keys.  Is your key restricted?  Do you have the Geocoding API enabled?

Comment: @geocodezip,  At the time I wrote it, I did not have the Geocoding API enable.  But after some testing, I did find that it needed to be enabled, and then I did enable it and it is working now.  If you want to post as answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the [Geocoding Web Service](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) you need to enable it in the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis)

Answer (score 0):

I just found it, I needed to enable the Geocoding API.